# Google Cloud Vertex AI Notebook Scheduled Runs Aren't Running Code?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I've followed their [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/quickstart-schedule-execution-console) to how to set up a managed Jupyter notebook and schedule a run, and I tossed in some pretty standard parameters and my bucket.

After setting up the schedule, however, the run just comes out as "Failed", and when I get "view results", I just get my code back (with no output indication). For some reason it's just not running. Ideas?

[image]

[2][image]

Answer (score 1):

I've tested and there is no reason to fail. Its working properly, I will just revise the steps I took and **check below where to see the results**:

- create the notebook
- open it , paste your code and press the button on top to schedule:
  [image]
- Check the name, of your execution, and consult the results (success or failing ) in the output bucket you have selected:

[image]

[image]

- there is file insile with the output, like `Untitled.ipynb`:

```json
"outputs": [
        {
          "traceback": [
            "\u001b[0;36m  File \u001b[0;32m\"/tmp/ipykernel_1/1690000547.py\"\u001b[0;36m, line \u001b[0;32m6\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;31m    print(\"Teste\", datetime.datetime.now(),\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m                                                 ^\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;31mSyntaxError\u001b[0m\u001b[0;31m:\u001b[0m unexpected EOF while parsing\n"
          ],
          "ename": "SyntaxError",
          "evalue": "unexpected EOF while parsing (1690000547.py, line 6)",
          "output_type": "error"
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Thank you! If this was able to be replicated my guess is there is likely a permissions issue and the Google Cloud UI just isn't friendly enough to indicate that.